# updating recycler view items from a different activity

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to update/refresh recycler view data from a different activity.

The setup I have is, I have a recycler view running in a fragment. Clicking on a recycler view item opens a new activity where user makes un update and data is saved in the database. Then going back(onBackClicked) to the fragment the recycler view is not updated. However the data is saved so if I close an app and restart the update is shown.

Can someone please guide me on how would I go on solving this issue.

Note: I'm using observer to observer items of the recycler view, but however since update is happening in a different activity recycler view is not updating. The observer works if I make update from the same fragment without opening a new activity.

Thank you in advance

Comment: the data list you pass to recyclerview adapter is not same as your list in your fragment or activity.both list is different copy.so you have to change data on the list of adapter class then notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fragment still has onResume method. Here you can update the data set list.
don't forget to update REcyclerView.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

   //update whatever your list
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() didn't work, I had to reset/set the adapter again on resume . I know it's not the best solution but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Since Fragments Doesnt have OnRestart LifeCycle ,You can use like this,

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
  super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
  if (isVisibleToUser) {
    //refresh recycleradapter with notifydatasetchanged here
    //recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) for Recyclerview. It will update recyclerview automatically when data source changes.

Comment: I'm using live data as well, it is still not updating

Comment: then check that your livedata's change function works or not

Answer (score 0):

I put a Recycler View into my fragment activity , which contains a number of Card View items 
But when I click on the Refresh button, those items are created just for the first time

And when the Fragment is loaded for the next time, the items are not fetch again, and this is done only for the first time.

```
public class PostFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<PostData> PostDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    PostDataAdapter adapter=new PostDataAdapter(PostDataList);
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_menu,container,false);
        recyclerView =view.findViewById(R.id.PostRecycleView);
        filldate();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return view;
    }

public void filldate() {

    //Start Get And Set Json Into Card View

    final String KeyUrl="http://www.rasamdev.ir/salehin/GetPost.php";
    final String KeyUsername="Key";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, KeyUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Start Pars
            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray("Posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String puid = object.getString("puid");
                        String Ptitr = object.getString("Ptitr");
                        String ptext = object.getString("ptext");
                        String pdate = object.getString("pdate");
                        String plike = object.getString("plike");
                        String pview = object.getString("pview");
                        String pimg = object.getString("pimg");
                        PostDataList.add(new PostData(pdate,ptext,puid,Ptitr,pimg,pview,plike));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            //End Pars


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(KeyUsername,"13581358r@R");
            return hashMap;
        }

    };


    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    //End
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.onResume();
}
```